# Unable to access jarfile docker

Tags: java, docker, jar

I am new to docker and trying to containerize a simple spring boot application. The docker file is as below.

```html
FROM openjdk:8<br>
RUN mkdir app<br>
ADD target/discovery.jar app/discovery.jar <br>
WORKDIR app<br>
RUN "pwd"<br>
RUN "ls"<br>
EXPOSE 8085<br>
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "discovery.jar "]
```

I am getting ***"Error: Unable to access jarfile discovery.jar"*** when I am trying to run the above image.

> docker run -p 8085:8085 discovery

Output while building the above docker image.

```html
Sending build context to Docker daemon  16.28MB<br>
Step 1/8 : FROM openjdk:8<br>
 ---> fe9f7b1e4fa0<br>
Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir app<br>
 ---> Running in 31cf087f541b<br>
Removing intermediate container 31cf087f541b<br>
 ---> c16f79c1776a<br>
Step 3/8 : ADD target/discovery.jar app/discovery.jar<br>
 ---> ff21016b781f<br>
Step 4/8 : WORKDIR app<br>
Removing intermediate container ec5b68b4d043<br>
 ---> 67fd0e77b057<br>
Step 5/8 : RUN "pwd"<br>
 ---> Running in f3d5f186a75a<br>
/app<br>
Removing intermediate container f3d5f186a75a<br>
 ---> 83928a000887<br>
Step 6/8 : RUN "ls"<br>
 ---> Running in b5c6a4af52cb<br>
discovery.jar<br>
Removing intermediate container b5c6a4af52cb<br>
 ---> d69d7ee14bb3<br>
Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 8085<br>
 ---> Running in 74a675cdd951<br>
Removing intermediate container 74a675cdd951<br>
 ---> 471bce4c390b<br>
Step 8/8 : ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "discovery.jar "]<br>
 ---> Running in b07b26fb3e2f<br>
Removing intermediate container b07b26fb3e2f<br>
 ---> 89e0ed2b16d6<br>
Successfully built 89e0ed2b16d6<br>
Successfully tagged discovery:latest<br>
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended
to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

Please note- the jar file is present in the working directory.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra space in

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "discovery.jar "]
```

and so it is being taken as part of the filename.  Remove the extra space before the final double quote.

Comment: (Style-wise, I'd suggest using `COPY` instead of `ADD` [`ADD` can automatically unpack archives, which can be confusing] and `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT` [to allow `docker run --rm -it myimage bash` for debugging] but that's secondary to your actual problem.)

Comment: Thank you!! It was indeed a space issue.